# Is it possible to dismiss Picture in Picture from an AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avkit, picture-in-picture

I'm using `AVPlayerViewController` and have set `canStartPictureInPictureAutomaticallyFromInline = true` which works as expected.

What i'd like to achieve, is if the app is opened whilst a video is in PiP mode, I want to automatically dismiss the PiP to put the video back into the `AVPlayerViewController`, as currently the video stays in PiP and the in-app video player shows the PiP placeholder.

I can listen to the delegate callbacks in `AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate` to know when PiP is active, but I can't figure out how to dismiss it.

`AVPictureInPictureController` has a `stopPictureInPicture()` function, but I don't know how to add an `AVPictureInPictureController` to my player.

I use an `AVPlayer` instance passed into the `AVPlayerViewController` but from what i'm seeing, I need an `AVPlayerLayer` to pass into `AVPictureInPictureController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `AVPlayerViewController` cannot fulfill your requirement because it does not expose its internally managed `pictureInPictureController(AVPictureInPictureController)` to developers.

To achieve your goal, you would need to implement a custom solution by creating your own `CustomPlayerViewController` and manually managing the `pictureInPictureController(AVPictureInPictureController)` instance.